# Why my model is valid ? It shoud not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I try to practice to making some tests using Rspec and I have a weird comportment. When I try to have an invalid model to follow the Red/Green/Refactor cycle, Rspec doesn't see any error.

I want to ensure release can't have an anterior date.

My model

```
class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :platform
  attr_accessible :date

  validates :date, presence: true
end
```

My spec file

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Release do
  before {@release = Release.new(date: Time.new(2001,2,3))}

  it{should respond_to :date}
  it{should respond_to :game}
  it{should respond_to :platform}

  describe "when date is not present" do
    before {@release.date = nil}
    it {should_not be_valid}
  end

  describe "when date is anterior" do
    before {@release.date = Time.now.prev_month}    
    it {should_not be_valid}
  end

end
```

My output

```
.....

Finished in 0.04037 seconds
5 examples, 0 failures
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but your tests are asserting that the conditions are not valid, and that is whats passing. RSpec is basically saying "Yep, these records are not valid like you asserted". R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `it { should_not be_valid }` you seem to think the receiver is `@release` (how would rspec know that?), but by default the implicit object is an instance of the class being `describe`d:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/subject/implicit-receiver

Use `subject { some_object }` for a explicit subject or `it { @release.should_not be_valid }`.

More on this:

http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2012/05/13/spec-smell-explicit-use-of-subject/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
it { @release.should_not be_valid}
```

instead.